# How to rectify syntax error ? ERROR: syntax error at or near "SELECT"

Tags: sql, syntax

I have the following query and it is generating error thet ERROR: syntax error at or near "SELECT". How can I get the vaöues of id from MappingForecastTyp,DimTypeForecastTyp and LinkForecastTyp?

```
INSERT INTO iomapping (id, name,version)
VALUES (gen_random_uuid(), 'Forecast Typ', 1);

WITH MappingForecastTyp AS
(
    SELECT d.id
    FROM iomapping d
    WHERE d.name = 'Forecast Typ'
),
DimTypeForecastTyp AS 
(
    SELECT att.id
    FROM attributetype att
    WHERE att.name = 'Forecast-Typ'
),
LinkForecastTyp AS 
(
    SELECT lt.id
    FROM linktype lt
    WHERE lt.name = 'Forecast'
)
INSERT INTO ocom.iodimensionattributecolumn
(id_linktype)  
VALUES (
    SELECT id from LinkTypeForecastTyp );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your VALUES section needs to be in the format

```
VALUES (
SELECT
…
FROM …
)
```

Comment: I did the following but getting Error:Syntax error at or near "SELECT"--

Insert into iodimensionattributecolumn() Values (...,SELECT id from MappingForecastTyp,....,)

Comment: You need to update your question with the new version of your SQL

Comment: okay..I updated the question with the new error after implementing the changes,,,

Comment: What you’ve written doesn’t match the pattern I gave. Everything in the VALUES section needs to be contained within a single SELECT statement

Comment: a single select statement will have a single from . That is not possible in this case, as the values are not comming from a single source or single from...

Comment: @NickW- I have shortened the question